# Search object by ID inside JSON file using Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-http

I have a JSON file like this one, sumarizing:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "country": "Brazil",
    "state": [
        {"id": "1", "name": "Acre", 
            "city": [ { "id": "1", "name": "Rio Branco"}, 
                      { "id": "2", "name": "Xapuri"}, 
                      { "id": "3", "name": "Cruzeiro do Sul"} ] 
}
```

I've created a 3 select options in a view, I have to select first the country, then based on the country ID, I need to fill the second select option with the states. After select the state, I need to fill the third select option with the cities.

I've created the PlacesService that return all JSON file:

```
  getPlaces() {
    return this.http.get('assets/database/places.json')
    .map( (res: Response) => res.json());
  }
```

Then in my component I call this service and works well:

```
this.placesService.getPlaces().subscribe(dados => this.places= dados);
```

Ok, I know how to return all data of JSON file, but I don't know how search a specific id inside of JSON file and returns only the object related of these ID.

I would like to know how solve this problem and what is the best practice, use all objects inside a unique json file or divide in others json files (ex: countries.json, states.json, cities.json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More efficient would be to divide them into separate flat arrays, and add "foreign keys" like `stateId` to cities and `countryId` to states.

If you decide not to divide, from a nested object you could for example find things with Array.prototype.find:

```
getCountry(id) {
    return this.countries.find(c => c.id === id);
}

getState(id, country) {
    return country.state.find(s => s.id === id);
}

getCity(id,state) {
    return state.city.find(c => c.id === id);
}

const city = this.getCity('2', getState('1', getCountry('1'))); // Xapuri
```

So as you see 3 flat arrays would make things simpler. You could find a city by id from all cities with a simple find call, or all cities of a state by filtering:

```
const acreCities = cities.filter(c => c.stateId === '1');
```

Comment: thanks! unfortunatelly someone negativate my question, but I've searched a lot and didn't find a good answer. You help me a lot.

Comment: Upvoted you back to zero. I don't really see the reason for the downvote either.. question was valid to me. Not nice to downvote without commenting and explaining the reason.